# Как образовать прилагательное от "день рождения"?

Tags: словообразование

Скажем, надо сказать о торте, спеченном специально для дня рождения. Но как сказать это одним словом по аналогии со "свадебный", "новогодний"? Говорят "именинный", но именины — это далеко не всегда день рождения.

Comment: Деньрожденный торт!

Хэппибездный пирог...

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

В ранешные времена люди очень любили шутить :

>(**Перевод Бориса Заходера**)

> -- Ай-ай, как жаль! Ты, наверно, слишком быстро бежал. Я надеюсь, ты не ушибся, маленький Пятачок?

 >-- Нет, спасибо, но он... он... Ох, Иа, он лопнул.

 >Наступило очень долгое молчание.

 >-- Мой шарик?-- наконец спросил Иа-Иа.

 >Пятачок кивнул.

 >**-- Мой деньрожденный подарок?**

 >-- Да, Иа,-- сказал Пятачок, слегка хлюпая носом.-- Вот он. Поздравляю тебя с днем рождения.

Comment: Очень рад, что вопрос понравился. И очень было интересно узнать ответы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Рожденческий. "День" при этом опускается, вопреки частому употреблению в Интернете. 
Реже - днерожденческий. В современном языке, увы, совершенно перестало употребляться.

//-----------

Конкретно в отношении пирога полагаю, что замена на "именинный пирог" вполне допустима. 
Это сочетание стало восприниматься неразрывным целым (почти как и сам "день рождения") - и, кстати, часто даже применительно к торту, совсем не пирогу, пусть и сладкому.

//----------- 
Поскольку ответ принят, вношу ясность по некоторым позициям. Я не претендую на нормативность этого слова. Претендую на то, что слово не новое - и перестало употребляться в живой речи (окказионализмы в Интернете фиксирую, но всерьез как аргумент не рассматриваю).

Как сказал, "днерожденческий" - внутренне противоречиво, поскольку явно образовано от "дневное рождение", а не наоборот.
Но варианты типа "деньрожденческий" противоречивы вдвойне и втройне. Это то ли от неумения образовывать форму "дне" (ср. дневной/дневный), то ли от восприятия "деньрождение" как одного слова.

Деньрожденный вообще никакой критики не выдерживает.

Да, чуть не забыл самое главное. Увидел вариант ***день-рожденческий***. Через дефис. Вот его я почему-то готов обсуждать всерьёз. Хотя он тоже не соответствует никакой норме, но почему-то режет глаз гораздо менее.

Comment: Спасибо за слово! Ломала-ломала язык, но до этого слова (днерожденческий) не додумалась. В словарях, правда, нет его. Зато яндекс выдал целых 462 ответа. Вы говорите, что перестало употребляться. Значит, раньше так говорили? Почему же в словарях нет? Как устаревшего хотя бы?

Comment: Ларf, ну что вы меня пывтаете, почему нет в словарях?  Я их не составлял. 
Потому, наверное, что образование нерегулярное, от образований с несогласованным определением  (Сущ + Сущ) прилагательные регулярно не образуются. Тут подмена на "[еже]днЕвное рождение", которое и дает "днерожденческий".

Могу только про "рожденческий" добавить. Помните, я где-то писал про слово "рожденник"? Ручаюсь, что я его слышал не только от Катаева. Как минимум от бабашки (флудить много не хочу), как и рассматриваемое. Форма легко восстанавливается из возрождение - возрожденческий. А про подмену уже писал.

Comment: >В современном языке,
увы, совершенно перестало употребляться.

По-моему, все совершенно наоборот! Слово *деньрожденческий* - современное сетевое слово, изобретенное совсем недавно, на волне интернетного общения. В советском дискурсе оно нигде не зафиксировано : ни в словарях, ни в литературе, ни в фильмах, ни в песнях, ни в разговорном варианте. У этого слова не было раньше своей ниши, а теперь она есть; это же касается и слова *деньрожденный*, которое придумал Заходер для своего перевода *Винни-Пуха*. Они оба наравне употребляются в ежедневном **трепе блогосферы**.

Comment: незнаю, чтоимел в виду grumant под "наоборот", но я "деньрожденческий" и "деньрожденский" всерьёз не рассматриваю. Ключевой момент - форма "***дне***роженческий". 

Надеюсь, что этот комментарий он все-таки не удалит. ;)

Answer (score 6):

Да, именины - это не день рождения. Хотя за годы советской власти слово именины стали употреблять в значении "день рождения", словари такое значение не зафиксировали.  Думаю, прилагательное от словосочетания "день рождения" не образуется.

Answer (score 1):

Да, мне тоже так кажется. Это, скорее всего, окказиональное слово. Поэтому, видимо, прилагательное от этого слова еще не попало в словарь.